# How to output Bibliography on separate page in 2-column layout (LyX)

Tags: lyx, page-breaking, two-column

I'm using LyX with the default document class & settings, except with 2-column layout. How do I get the Bibliography to output on a separate page? I tried inserting a New Page, but that just bumps it up to the top of the next column. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `\clearpage`, i.e. Insert --> Formatting --> Clear Page instead of a New page.

If you want the bibliography to be printed in one column rather than two, add an ERT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) just before the bibliography, and write `\onecolumn` in it.